# Dagger 2: Gradle module dependency with implementation in another module

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to set up a project in which I have two modules `common-lib` and `app`.

The lib module has its own Dagger component and modules, and it's supposed to be flavor agnostic.

Now, part of it depends on flavor specific resource values declared in the module `app`, so I tried abstracting the component through an interface and  override its implementation in the module `app`.

Dagger module declare in `common-lib` gradle module, satisfying dependencies with NoOp implementations.

```
    @Module
public class NetworkConfigModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HeaderParams providesHeaderParams(NoOpHeaderParams noOpHeaderParams){
        return noOpHeaderParams;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AppHostsProvider providesAppHostsProvider(NoOpAppHostsProvider noOpAppHostsProvider){
        return noOpAppHostsProvider;
    }
}
```

Dagger module declare in `app` gradle module, satisfying dependencies with the actual implementation.

```
@Module
public class NetworkConfigModule {

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    HeaderParams providesHeaderParams(KaufdaHeaderParams kaufdaHeaderParams){
        return kaufdaHeaderParams;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    AppHostsProvider providesAppHostsProvider(KaufdaAppHostsProvider implementation){
        return implementation;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, because Dagger just doesn't override the Module class, but that's somehow expected.

My question is, how I can set up my Dagger modules so I can use `HeaderParams` and `AppHostsProvider` interfaces in `common-lib`, but I inject their implementations in `app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just handle the component creation in your `app`.

In your app you know the actual modules and classes that you want to use. If you create the component there, you can just add the right module to the component, inject your `common-lib` classes and be done.

---

If you don't want to handle the injection in your app, you would need to define an interface, e.g.

```
interface NetworkComponentHolder {
    NetworkComponent getNetworkComponent();
}
```

which then in turn you could implement with your `Application` in `app`. Again, you would have to create the component and modules in your `app`, but then from your module you can call

```
((NetworkComponentHolder) getApplication()).getNetworkComponent().inject(this);
```

This would be the 2 possibilities without using reflection.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your answer, it sounds good, but I am still struggling to place every part of your second suggestion...

If NetworkComponentHolder, and NetworkComponent are both in the `common-lib` gradle module, ain't I facing the same issue because I can't provide the implementation of their dependencies?

Comment: @mdelolmo You would make the application implement the interface, then you can get a reference to the application in the library, and access the component by using the interface. this is if you need to call `component.inject(this)` some place in your module